# not losing state when refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a Simple WebApp in React.js, that can add food to a cart and see it or finally order it.
when I add food, my cart updates and can see data but when I refresh the page, data will be gone
how can save data and when I refresh the page still can see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should be storing you data inside SessionStorage or LocalStorage, Redux Persist, etc etc (other options available). React will not persist your data for you. I would suggest giving this article a read. https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-methods-to-persisting-state-between-page-reloads-in-react-8fc9abd3fa2f

Answer (score 2):

You have different solutions to store your data:

1. [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) with no expiration time
2. [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is cleared when the page session ends
3. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is a predictable state container
4. [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) is designed to share data that can be considered globally for a tree of React components

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the state of your shopping cart somewhere you can do that server side. You can store it in Session state. When you refresh you refill the page from Session state.